# In JetBrains TeamCity, can I build images with names the same as the repository that triggered the build?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, teamcity

Good morning,
I am trying TeamCity in order to speed up our workflow; in our company we have many repositories on bitbucket, all with the same structure (a Dockerfile in the root that needs to be built), and all to be pushed to the same registry.
Currently, I have a simple python script that responds to bitbucket hooks, builds the image and pushes it to the registry. Works pretty well, but I was looking for something more solid and with a web interface.
I am trying TeamCity and seems nice, but I'd like to not manually create every single repository as a separate build pipeline.
Can I attach all the VCS roots to one project and just tell in the configuration "make the image name the same as the repository name"?

I saw that there are "build parameters" that I can use to parameterize the name, but I read through JetBrains support and all I could find related to VCS had the vcs root name in the parameter name itself, which is not useful in my case of course.

Comment: you could give the vcs root the same name as repository has and then use it via build parameters?

Comment: What build parameter has the name of the VCS that triggered the build?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one VCS root in you build configuration, you can use `%vcsroot.url%` build parameter to get the repository url.

Source: [TeamCity docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html#VCS+Parameters)